# For Integer type variable, does '=' operator equate the value or the reference?

Tags: java, operators

**CODE 1 :**

```
Car car1 = new Car();
Car car2 = new Car();
car2.setColor("Green");
car2.setModel("I20");
car1 = car2;
System.out.println(car1.getColor() + " , " + car1.getModel());
System.out.println(car2.getColor() + " , " + car2.getModel());
car1.setColor("Red");
car1.setModel("I10");
System.out.println(car1.getColor() + " , " + car1.getModel());
System.out.println(car2.getColor() + " , " + car2.getModel());
```

**Output :**

```
Green , I20
Green , I20
Red , I10
Red , I10
```

Here the `car1 = car2;` make the `car1` object refer to `car2` object thus any further change to `car1` is equivalent to changing the `car2` object as both are referencing to same value.

**CODE 2 :**

```
Integer c = 5;
Integer d = 10;
System.out.println(c + ", " + d);
c = d;
System.out.println(c + ", " + d);
c = 7;
System.out.println(c + ", " + d);
```

**Output :**

```
5, 10
10, 10
7, 10
```

Here also after `c = d;` both `c` and `d` refer to the same value then why changing the value of `c` does not change the value of `d`?

Comment: `=` modifies the variable, not the object.

Comment: Changing the value of a variable is very different than modifying the state of an object.  Changing your mailing address does nothing to modify the house at your old address, and it certainly won't change the address of the other people still living there.

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ - I think the reason is more that `Integer` variables are references - `c = d; c = 7;` modifies `d` no more than `Foo d = new Foo(42); Foo c = d; c = new Foo(69);` does.

Comment: in one snippet you write `something.setSomethingElse()` in the other you write `something = somethingElse`, that simply is doing completely different things.

Comment: hi @OliverCharlesworth that is a good one... c = 7 will be c = new Integer(7);

Answer (score 1):

Integer is immutable. This means it cannot be changed that way. You are not allowed to change its internal fields. You are not allowed to change to what place in the memory it points to, but you are able to change the value that is assigned to the reference of given Integer. In example, when you write

```
Integer i = 5;
Integer j = 10;
i = j;
```

this doesn't mean that from now `i` is pointing to the same place in the memory where `j` points. It just assigns the value stored in `j` to `i`, because only that is allowed for immutable types.

Answer (score 0):

No because you assign value d in c not inverse. 
Do you understand ?
If you desirre assing value c in d you write d = c for d recive reference of c